# Il est possible/ Il est certain/ Il paraît/ Il croit

Tags: expressions, choix-de-mot, subjonctif

I must put one of the phrases in the title on the empty place in the sentence:

> ______ que les trottinettes soient bientôt interdites sur nos trottoirs.

The options are:

- `Il est possible`
- `Il est certain`
- `Il paraît`
- `Il croit`

Which is the correct option and why?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As the conjugation is a subjunctive, one can eliminate :

> - Il paraît
> - Il est certain
> - Il croit

(and by the way, 'Il croit' means 'he believes' : it's not an impersonal form like the others).

Note that all those 3 forms would be acceptable with an indicative (future because of the 'bientôt'), for example :

> **Il paraît** que les trottinettes **seront** bientôt interdites sur nos trottoirs

So the only valid one is :

> **Il est possible** que les trottinettes soient bientôt interdites sur nos trottoirs.

Here are some other elements that would fit in here :

> - Il semble
> - Il est à craindre
> - Il est souhaitable

---

As for the why, it's dictated by usage, and there a lot of exceptions but :

- For a possibility or a wish, it's mostly subjunctive mood.
- For something certain or obvious, it's mostly indicative mood.

Comment: *Il cro**î**t* means *he grows*... ;-)

Comment: @jlliagre oups, corrigé.

Comment: At this point of my studies, I had only heard of subjunctif and didn't know what it really was. This problem and your answer made me do some searching. Now I know what it's about, Thank you for the clean explanation.